# MongoServerSelectionError: unable to get local issuer certificate in Mongoose library

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ssl-certificate, cpanel

Whenever I try to connect to MongoDB through mongoose library in cPanel I get an error.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://myusername:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/main', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
```

```
MongoDB connection error: MongoServerSelectionError: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ddxnotes/nodevenv/ddx-notes/20/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'example.mongodb.server:1' => [ServerDescription],
      'example.mongodb.server:2' => [ServerDescription],
      'example.mongodb.server:3' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-d3kjn0-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

If it can't be solved please tell me how do I configure my driver to accept unverified certificate

I tried

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://myusername:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/main', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    sslValidateCertificate: false,
    sslCA: []
})
```

but `MongoDB connection error: MongoParseError: option sslvalidatecertificate is not supported`